# finding records worked on one project

Tags: mysql

I have two columns i.e. ID, Project 
I want to count the number of IDs who worked on a specific project

```
ID Project 
4    A
5    B
9    C
4    A
5    A
4    D
5    B
```

In this example I want to find the number of times ID number 4 worked on project A.

When I use count and apply where condition I get all records who worked on A including 5.

```
select count(id) from projects where project like 'A';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you If you columns name is  `ID, Project`

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM `projects` WHERE `ID` = '4' AND `Project` = 'A';
```

else

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `projects` WHERE `id` = '4' AND `project` = 'A';
```

Comment: Thank you, it did the trick. I have another query to prepare similar to this but I will post is in a different question

Answer (score 2):

`select count(id) from projects where project like '%A%' and id = '4';`